Are there known bounds for the median of a negative binomial distribution based on its parameters?
This seems like an innocent enough question to me, but I could not find a satisfactory answer when I did some digging. The binomial distribution has a closed form median and the Poisson distribution has a simple set of very tight bounds, and these were both easy to track down e.g. on Wikipedia. If I try to (perhaps foolishly) draw parallels to continuous distributions, I could imagine that the binomial pairs with the normal (which has a simple closed form median), that the Poisson pairs with the exponential (which has a simple closed form median), and that the negative binomial pairs with the gamma. From what I could tell in the Wikipedia article for the gamma distribution, its median is very hard to pin down - there are various approaches to arriving at approximations and bounds, but there are none that, all at once, are simple, are tight, and always work. Does this difficulty with the gamma shed light on a similar challenge with the negative binomial? Is there any key research that has been done on this question / is it an area of active research?
EDIT: Having re-read this, almost certainly Poisson should be replaced with geometric in my discrete-continuous analogy above...

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There are, but the articles seem to be paywalled by Springer.  But this may be accessible: https://www.academia.edu/59178073/Bounds_for_median_and_50_percetage_point_of_binomial_and_negative_binomial_distribution

I'd start by looking  at the connection between the negative binomial cdf and the binomial cdf
